# Does uniqueness of a solution to a perturbation approximation imply local uniqueness to the original equation?

Tags: taylor-expansion, systems-of-equations, homotopy-theory, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^p$ is infinitely differentiable, where $p\ge m+n$.

Define $g_{x,y}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^p$ by $g_{x,y}(\sigma)=f(\sigma x,\sigma^2 y)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$, and suppose that:

$$g_{x,y}(\sigma)=g_{0}+g_{x,1}\sigma+g_{x,y,2}\sigma^2+g_{x,y,3}\sigma^3+O(\sigma^4)$$

as $\sigma\rightarrow 0$.

Finally define $h_{x,y}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^p$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$, by:

$$h_{x,y}(\sigma)=g_{0}+g_{x,1}\sigma+g_{x,y,2}\sigma^2+g_{x,y,3}\sigma^3,$$

so $h_{x,y}$ is a Taylor approximation to $g_{x,y}$, and a perturbation type approximation to $f$.

Now, suppose that for all $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $y_1,y_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$:

$$\left( h_{x_1,y_1}(1)=h_{x_2,y_2}(1)\right)\rightarrow\left(x_1=x_2\wedge y_1=y_2 \right).$$

Given this, can one prove that there exists some open sets $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ and $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ with $0\in U$ and $0\in V$ such that for all $x_1,x_2\in U$ and $y_1,y_2\in V$:

$$\left( f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)\right)\rightarrow\left(x_1=x_2\wedge y_1=y_2 \right)?$$

Can one say anything more about $f$ than this? I.e. might it be the case that for all $x_1\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $y_1\in\mathbb{R}^n$, there are finitely (countably?) many $x_2\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $y_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$?

One potential avenue might be considering homotopies between $g_{x,y}$ and $h_{x,y}$, so I am tagging with homotopy theory.

Comment: Does the question in the title hold for functions of a single variable?

Comment: That's a fair question. Taking a first order approximation to the system above with $n=0$ means that the supposition becomes $x_1 f'(0)=x_2 f'(0)\rightarrow x_1=x_2$. Thus $f'(0)\ne 0$. By the inverse function theorem then, $f$ is locally invertible, and hence the claim holds. This was a helpful question as it hadn't occurred to me use the IVT before.

Comment: With a second order approximation, we still have that $f'(0)\ne 0$ as $x^2$ is not injective. With a third order approximation, either $f'(0)\ne 0$ or $f'''(0) \ne 0$. In the latter case, the IVT implies $f''$ is locally invertible, which is not enough. Does suggest the potential beginnings of a proof in the case of interest though.

Comment: $f(σx,σ^2y)$ seems unusual. Is there some motivation for this?

Comment: Yes. In context it is natural for some parameters to disappear at a different rate to others. Given that the proof was more straightforward in the case without the $\sigma^2$ at the moment I'm assessing if I can get the required results in my context in that case.